# packagist error when adding bitbucket repository

Tags: bitbucket, packagist

I get the following error when trying to add a repository.

---

Uncaught Exception: [RuntimeException] Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@bitbucket.org:doppy/doppy.git' '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-doppy-doppy.git/' Cloning into bare repository '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-doppy-doppy.git'... Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

---

The repository is public and when I copy and run the command locally I don't get any error.
I guess this an issue on the packagist server itself with the bitbucket servers?

side note: yeah, I understand it is a silly repo. I fully intend to remove it when done testing and cleanup my own mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feedback from composer user mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-users/ciGcpehsvy4

I think the problem is we don't support git@ connections to bitbucket as 
we don't have an ssh key set up for them. Make sure you use the HTTPS 
clone URL and that should work:

https://bitbucket.org/doppy/doppy.git

Cheers